# C Pointer of another pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to get value of variable **A** from the void pointer **B**

Casting void pointer to **char *** give me wrong unreadable value

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *A = "1020304050";

    void *B = &A;

    printf("%p -- %p -- %s -- %s", &A, B, A, (char *) B);

    return 0;
}
```

This is my result:

`0x7ffc2db2f820 -- 0x7ffc2db2f820 -- 1020304050 -- @`

should be

`0x7ffc2db2f820 -- 0x7ffc2db2f820 -- 1020304050 -- 1020304050`

Comment: Doesn't your compiler issue any warnings?

Comment: Because `%s` is not the right format specifier for a pointer.

Comment: A real-world example of why this is desirable would be preferable to code with no context.

Comment: How (or why) is this C++?

Comment: c or c++? they are two different languages with different rules

Comment: Is a C or a C++ question? Use tags appropiately. If it's C++, do you know about of `std::string`?

Comment: Given `void *B = &A;`, just what do you expect `B` to hold?  (hint - it's **NOT** any form of `char` string...)

Comment: The result you posted is enough to understand all...

Comment: @Blaze no warning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `printf` call you're casting the value of `B` to `char *`, but that's not what you assigned to it.  You assigned `&A` which has  type `char **`.

You need to either assign `A` to `B`:

```
void *B = A;
printf("%p -- %p -- %s -- %s", (void *)&A, (void *)B, A, (char *) B);
```

Or cast `B` to a `char **` and dereference the casted pointer:

```
void *B = &A;
printf("%p -- %p -- %s -- %s", (void *)&A, (void *)B, A, *(char **)B);
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
printf("%p -- %p -- %s -- %s", &A, B, A, *(char **)B);
```

Answer (score 1):

A pointer to `A` is stored in `B`.

It means you have to dereference `B` to get the value of `A`.

To dereference a pointer, you can use `*` operator.

You casted the pointer `&A` to `void*`, so you have to cast the pointer back.

The type of a pointer to `A` is `char**`.

In conclusion, you can read the value of `A` via `*(char**)B`.